# Another custom UISwitch question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiswitch

I have looked all over stack overflow, for the answer to this question, and i can only find ways which worked on 4.1 and below, but for 4.2.1 and above, i can't find a new way of getting the text of ON and OFF to change. Is there a way of changing it to say Yes and No. 
This is what I have currently:

```
UISwitch *switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [switchControl addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    switchControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    switchControl.on = value;
    [cell addSubview:switchControl];
    [switchControl release];
```

What would be the easiest way of changing the text of the UISwitch? Or would it be easier if i was to make two images and using animation to make them flow, like it is a normal UISwitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up a custom switch class. Hope this helps. http://cl.ly/4OQN

EDIT:
Also, maybe try this:

```
switchView = [[UICustomSwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[switchView setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f,260.0f)];
[switchView setLeftLabelText: @"Foo"];
[switchView setRightLabelText: @"Bar"];
[[switchView rightLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0f]];
[[switchView leftLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0f]];
[[switchView leftLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```